# Capture Network Connectivity Event

Tags: java, network-programming, windows-xp

Is it possible to capture network events using Java?

For example, when I connect my ethenet adapter to a hub there is 'connectivity' and this is detected by windows XP and a 'bubble' displayed to the user. Does Windows also broadcast an event which can be captured by applications and more specifically applications written in Java?

Comment: I don't think any such events are broadcast, as all applications I've ever seen keep checking "manually" if a connection is available.

Comment: @Kerubu, do you want to check LAN connection or Internet Connectivity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know there is not an event for this that Java can detect -- it's very OS specific.  What you can do is poll the available network interfaces every so often.

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> e = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();
```

Comment: This is what I suspected. I want to avoid polling if I can. I'll probably just have to use a user initiated check/search.

Answer (score 1):

The best you could do is detect whether or not you have network connectivity by creating a thread which periodically polls a URL that you can trust will be up. Detecting network events in windows would require a JNI call to Windows APIs.

Comment: Poll which URL? I think, he doesnot mean to detect Internet connection. " when I connect my ethenet adapter to a hub there is 'connectivity' "... He wants  to detect the ethernet connection event as it is detected by windows .

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I mean.